# Pipe character appearing in the c code when edited using eclipse

Tags: eclipse

My project is in a remote linux file which I mounted in my mac. I am editing the C project with custom defined indentation in eclipse. When I open the edited C code in linux, I see "|"(pipe) in indentation. I havent used eclipse before and not sure why the pipe is appearing?

example:

```
if (a)
 | if (b) {
 |   | c = 10;
 |   | d = 10;
 |   | c+d;
 |  }
 }
```

Comment: are you sure they are not visual indicators for `TAB`?

Comment: If you look at the source using `cat` in a console you will see that the pipe characters are not really there. In Eclipse they should also be fainter than the normal characters, and probably more like *lines* than pipe characters really. What they do is help you with indentation. It's a purely visual aid in the editor.

Comment: Please paste the **actual** text, not some "example". If the "piper character" magically does not get copied, it might be a phantom ...